# Reloading a page when a value is clicked with java

Tags: java, jquery

I have a simple little program that takes radio buttons and saves what the values are.  When a user wants to change what a value is he/she clicks a button which enables an edit mode for the user to change the value.  If however the user decides to cancel the edit after they have changed a value the value doesn’t get set back to what it was before the edit.  The cancel button right now just turns off the edit while leaving whatever values there are in the radio buttons instead of resetting them to the previous save.

The Java:

```
if(action.equals("edit") || edit){
   riskProfileBean.setEditMode(true);
}else if(action.equals("cancel") || (action.equals("changeTab") && upgradeSuccess)){
   riskProfileBean.setEditMode(false);
}
```

The HTML:

```
<td><pp:button href="javascript:nav('cancel')" ssid="G_ALERT 004"> </pp:button></td>
```

I know I have to reset everything in the else/if but I'm not sure how to reload the page(I know I have to do that with JavaScript) then during the reload populate the radio buttons with the previous save information.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you tag the framework you are using if any? Your Java code is Java, or did you mean Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that difficult. Before you go for edit, save all your information in a bean

```
chrisBean.setAllInformation(chrisInfo);
```

Now add that to your application session.

```
addInSession(chrisBean);
```

Now in case, the `cancel` button is clicked, `get all the fields saved in the bean which is saved in session`.

**Note :** Since , i do not know the proper scope of your application , i have given you an algorithmic view of what you need to do. I have done the same for several of my applications .